# Python3 import performance

Tags: performance, python-3.x, import

If I had 100 imports, would my program perform worse due to Python looking up names during runtime (and looking through my all 100 imports)?

I am creating a game and it would be far easier to describe each area as a separate module containing single class.

Comment: Yes it would perform worse, how much worse is the important question. Chances are you wouldn't notice it.

Comment: There would be a performance hit when all the `import`s are loaded, but looking up a name in the current namespace is dictionary-based, hence `O(1)`. Python doesn't need to *look through* the imports, as you specify which module it should be looking in (e.g. `import random; random.choice`). It is not clear how your second paragraph relates to the first.

Comment: Just to say that externally, each module contains only one word.

Comment: Oh, if you mean would it be more efficient to have all the classes in one file or `import` them one-at-a-time from a whole bunch of files, I doubt you'd see that much difference. One per file seems a bit much, though; could you identify groups of related classes that would share a file?

Comment: All default areas are described in one file, however, I plan on letting user defining his own and if the game happens to be successful, that can be a shitload of areas.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, you forgot to add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There would be an initial performance hit the first time the modules are loaded.  The second, third, fourth, ..., times the modules are loaded, Python gets them from its cache, so no performance hit at all.

Having said that, the performance should be minor -- still, being a game, do all the imports up front.